# Issues in moving build configuration in teamcity

Tags: teamcity, buildconfiguration

I am working on Team-city 9.x.  I have some build failures in one of the release project. although we have disabled the build and we do not want to run the build.

I am trying to move the build to another project (Disabled builds) but I cannot move the build.

Since I am getting an error as below

[image: Click on this link you can see the error]

So I created the same VCS roots same as the release project for disabled-build  project but still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like the VCS root hasn't been created at a level that can be shared by both projects from it's current location.

If you move the original VCS root to a level that is above both the current project and the one you're moving it too, it can be shared by both and you'll be able to move the project.

[image]

I would move this to `<Root project>` initially to help you move the project and then determine the best location for it depending on where it's being used in other build configurations

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes Thankyou so much it worked. options for moving VCS root has only root directory it does not show another projects. but however i could re attach the VCS root. THankyou